# sprintf precision typecasting leading to compilation warning

Tags: c++, integer, printf, precision

I have the below C++ code which issues a compilation warning as shown below.

**Case 1:**

```
char temp_buffer[80];
double **data;
....
sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", sizeof(temp_buffer), **data);
```

Compilation warning:

```
extension.C:1031:41: warning: field precision specifier '.*' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]
 1031 |                 sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", sizeof(temp_buffer), **data);
      |                                       ~~^~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                         |    |
      |                                         int  long unsigned int
```

I am fixing the warning by type-casting the `sizeof` to int like below.

**Case 2:**

```
char temp_buffer[80];
double **data;
...
sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", (int)sizeof(temp_buffer), **data);
```

But now I get the below warning:

```
extension/extension.C:1031:39: warning: \u2018%.*g\u2019 directive writing between 1 and 87 bytes into a region of size 80 [-Wformat-overflow=]
 1031 |                 sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", (int)sizeof(temp_buffer), **data);
      |                                       ^~~~
extension/extension.C:1031:38: note: assuming directive output of 86 bytes
 1031 |                 sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", (int)sizeof(temp_buffer), **data);
      |                                      ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:873,
                 from /opt/python/python-3.9/include/python3.9/Python.h:25,
                 from /codemill/dhamodha/projects/base/src/lib/despython/desnumpyinit.h:19,
                 from extension/extension.C:8:
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:36:34: note: \u2018__builtin___sprintf_chk\u2019 output between 2 and 88 bytes into a destination of size 80
   36 |   return __builtin___sprintf_chk (__s, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   37 |       __bos (__s), __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
```

I was under the assumption that '*' in the precision internally coerces the `long unsigned int` to `int`. But had that been the case the new warning wouldn't happen if I introduce `sizeof` typecasting.

Can someone help me in understand what's going on and solve the warnings?

**Case 3:**

Say I modify the `temp_buffer` to size `8`, then I see both warnings:

```
extension/extension.C:1033:20: warning: \u2018%.*g\u2019 directive writing between 1 and 310 bytes into a region of size 8 [-Wformat-overflow=]
 1033 |   sprintf(temp_b, "%.*g", sizeof(temp_buffer), **data);
      |                    ^~~~
extension/extension.C:1033:19: note: assuming directive output of 12 bytes
 1033 |   sprintf(temp_b, "%.*g", sizeof(temp_buffer), **data);
      |                   ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:873,
                 from /opt/python/python-3.9/include/python3.9/Python.h:25,
                 from /codemill/dhamodha/projects/base/src/lib/despython/desnumpyinit.h:19,
                 from extension/extension.C:8:
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:36:34: note: \u2018__builtin___sprintf_chk\u2019 output between 2 and 311 bytes into a destination of size 8
   36 |   return __builtin___sprintf_chk (__s, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   37 |       __bos (__s), __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244356/discussion-on-question-by-vinu-sprintf-precision-typecasting-leading-to-compilat). If you have advice to contribute that is relevant to the problem described in the question, post an answer.

Comment: Use `snprintf` to avoid buffer overflow

Answer (score 3):

You could assign the width before use:

```
int width = sizeof(temp_buffer);
sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", width, **data);
```

The warning would go away, that however would not solve the underlying problem. If you want to avoid potential buffer overflow, a reasonable option would be to use the correct size:

```
sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", (int)(sizeof(temp_buffer)) - 8, **data);
```

In your original code what you're saying is that you want the number of decimal places to be the size of the buffer, that leaves no space for the signs, scientific notation and the nul byte. You need to pass a decimal part size small enough so that all of those can fit the the destination buffer.

Even though the compiler mentions 7 bytes I believe 8 bytes would be prefereable, 2 for the signs, 1 for the dot, 1 for the `e`, 3 for the exponent and 1 for the nul byte.

Though I think having a buffer large enough to have the longest possible representation could be safer, given that the longest possible representation of a double [can be as much as 758 bytes](https://godbolt.org/z/6MKb4Thnz) (though this may not be the case for all compilers), a buffer that can take 800 bytes would be able to deal with this, assuming the above byte count, consistent with the compilation with **gcc 11.3**.

That all being said the correct way to go about this is to use the much safer `snprintf` which allows you to pass the maximum buffer size as argument:

```
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%.*g", (int)sizeof buffer - 8, **data);
```

---

As for your different use cases, [the behavior is undefined](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3) without the cast because you do not pass the correct type of arguments to a `...` parameter [as is `sprintf` third parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (in most cases the size of an `unsigned long` is larger than `int`), as such the compiler is not mandated to issue any warnings. The fact that it does can be considered a courtesy, `clang` for example issues no warnings, which is perfectly fine as per the standard definition of undefined behavior linked above.

To know the specific reason why in some cases there are the two different warnings and in others only one is a matter that is specific to the compiler, I consider it to be speculative to try to figure out why this is so.

Regarding the overflow values issued in the warnings, I found it curious and asked a question regarding it, the answers are elucidative:

- [Strange warning when calling sprintf with .* width specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72064283/6865932)

Comment: I see that from the error message you are adding the "-7". But could you help me understand. If I have sizeof(temp_buffer), I didn't get the warning. But with (int)sizeof(temp_buffer) I am getting. Why so ?

Comment: Just to confirm, does that mean size_t is being considered as a bigger number and it worked but not when type-casted to int ?

Comment: But the case 3 (in my question) still throws both the warning. In this case, it doesn't seem to suppress the warning which makes me confusing

Comment: @Vinu I updated my answer, hope that clarifies it, if not feel free to ask.

Comment: IMO, magic number 7 deserves review.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you're right, it's too few bytes, I think 9 would be the number.

Comment: @anastaciu, what value requires 9?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica check my edited  answer.

Comment: "1 for the integral part" --> that is already included in the precision with `"%.*g"`.  This differs from `"%.*e"`, so back to 8.

Comment: 758 is reasonable, in theory, as the [exact value](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485) of `-DBL_TRUE_MIN` would need about that.  Trouble occurs with attempting such high precision via `"%.*g"` is we rely on the quality of implementation and hope `*printf()` will print correctly and truncate the trailing zeros.  My `int len = printf("%.*g", 2000, -DBL_TRUE_MIN); printf("\n%d\n", len);` resulted in 1031 characters, being correct only to ~43 digits.  YMMV.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, correct again, the integral digit is included. 758 bytes is the  gcc max number of digits I got, and I ran with it, I can see this is an extremely complex issue and I appreciate all the knowledge you have been passing along, thank you very much.

Comment: @anastaciu The larger issue is that high precision printout via `*printf()` beyond `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG + 3` precision is treading on ever thinning ice.  Good that your implementation rendered a quality answer, yet beyond _some_ TBD point, do not count on it.  For OP here, defensive code would use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica for sure.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone help me in understand what's going on and solve the warnings?

With `sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", precision, **data);`, `precision` controls the number of digits in the significand of exponential display.

Consider `sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", 5, 1234567e10);` would form "1.2346e+16".

Rather than give a precession that is the size of the buffer, account for other characters like the sign, decimal point, 'e', and exponent (for common `double`, might be 4 characters like "-300") and the *null character*.  In this case 8.

```
#define G_OVERHEAD 8
sprintf(temp_buffer, "%#.*g", (int) sizeof temp_buffer - G_OVERHEAD, **data);
```

This code is risky as `G_OVERHEAD` may be larger.  Consider startup code that determines worst case, such as the following.

```
int g_overhead = snprintf(0, 0, "%#.*g", 2, -DBL_TRUE_MIN) + 1 /*\0*/ - 2 /*Precision*/;

// Common result: 8 for -4.9e-324
```