# Strange warning when calling sprintf with .* width specifier

Tags: c, printf, double, precision, buffer-overflow

For the following code:

https://godbolt.org/z/WcGf9hEs3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    
    char temp_buffer[8];
    double val = 25.3;

    sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", sizeof(temp_buffer), val);
    printf("%s", temp_buffer);
}
```

I get the warnings in gcc 11.3 with `-Wall` flag:

```
<source>:8:29: warning: field precision specifier '.*' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'long unsigned int' [-Wformat=]
    8 |     sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", sizeof(temp_buffer), val);
      |                           ~~^~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                             |    |
      |                             int  long unsigned int
<source>:8:27: warning: '%.*g' directive writing between 1 and 310 bytes into a region of size 8 [-Wformat-overflow=]
    8 |     sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", sizeof(temp_buffer), val);
      |                           ^~~~
<source>:8:26: note: assuming directive output of 12 bytes
    8 |     sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", sizeof(temp_buffer), val);
      |                          ^~~~~~
<source>:8:5: note: 'sprintf' output between 2 and 311 bytes into a destination of size 8
    8 |     sprintf(temp_buffer, "%.*g", sizeof(temp_buffer), val);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In fact the size of the destination buffer is too small to store the value given the size argument, but what's with the warning `'sprintf' output between 2 and 311 bytes into a destination of size 8`? Where does that 311 bytes value come from?

If I cast the number of the decimal places to `int`, *i.e.* `(int)sizeof(temp_buffer)` the potential overflow numbers drop dramatically:

```
'sprintf' output between 2 and 16 bytes into a destination of size 8
```

Comment: The range of a IEEE-754 double is roughly 1e-308 to 1e308. So the 311 is probably related to that somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the code:

- `sprintf` expects an `int` value for the `*` place holder and you pass a `size_t` which may have a different size and representation.
- the call may have undefined behavior because you request a precision that is the length of the destination array, which may produce output that exceeds said length.

Passing `sizeof(temp_buffer)` is an error, the compiler seems confused about the actual argument values and makes no particular assumption about the precision value or the number to convert. Yet they seem mistaken when they document the output can be 2 to 311 bytes:

- for the value `25.3`, the exact representation of the closest IEEE 754 number is `25.300000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125`, requiring 52 bytes.
- the output for the largest number via `printf("%.1000g", -0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023)` has 310 characters, thus requiring 311 bytes, which seems to be the reason for the `2 to 311 bytes`.
- yet a `%.*g` conversion can actually produce more than 311 bytes: `printf("%.1000g", -5e-324)` produces 758 characters on both macOS and linux.

When you cast `sizeof(temp_buffer)` as `(int)`, the compiler determines that the precision is `8` (a non trivial optimisation) and determines that the output can be as small as `2` bytes (a single digit and a null terminator) but no longer than 16 (`-`, a digit, `.`, 7 decimals, `e`, `-` and as many as 3 exponent digits plus a null terminator. That is still potentially too much for an 8 byte array.

Good job for warning the programmer about this potential undefined behavior!

Use `snprintf()`, a larger array and pass `(int)(sizeof(temp_buffer) - 9)` as the precision to get as many decimals as will fit in the worst case. It is difficult to produce as many decimals as will fit in all cases and may require multiple tries or complex postprocessing.

Comment: @anastaciu: There are different approaches for handling large precision values when converting floating point numbers: one can output trailing zeroes (which would be removed for `%g`) as long as converting the string back to a `double` produces the same exact value. With this approach, small values do not produce more than 18 decimals or so but large values can produce as many as 311 bytes. Alternately the conversion can produce the exact decimal representation of the floating point value, only rounded for the requested number of decimal places. In this case, as much as 759 bytes are needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Where does that 311 bytes value comes from?

Compiler is confused.

`"%.*g", 8` may output 15<sup>*1</sup>  + 1 (for the *null character*) characters, but not 311.

I suspect the compiler is making the wrong prediction that printing `-DBL_MAX` would use 310 + 1 characters, expect for the fact that `%g` switches to exponential notation for extreme values - that is the beauty of `"%g"`, limited output.  If it did not switch to exponential notation then that extreme output would be like `"%.*f", (int) 0`.

```
int main(void) {
  char buffer[1000];
  char temp_buffer[8];
  int len = sprintf(buffer, "%.*g", (int) sizeof(temp_buffer), -DBL_MAX);
  printf("%d <%s>\n", len, buffer);
  len = sprintf(buffer, "%.*f", (int) 0, -DBL_MAX);
  printf("%d <%s>\n", len, buffer);
}
```

Output

```
15 <-1.7976931e+308>
310 <-179769313486231570814527423731704356798070565449239578069709514447683386590106403234437238318580897337933920052621128987133479958537240295444402082043505598186819583097828779632178833278408753356733764414284292236482024122876814115690851853178733231033249466834451356736736928870307247739983885979597249860971>
```

---

<sup>*1</sup>

```
1 1 1   8-1   1 1  3 --> 15
- d . ddddddd e - eee
```

Comment: More decimals are produced for very small numbers: `printf("%.1000g", -5e-324)` produces 758 characters.

Comment: @chqrlie True for your case, but OP's code has a precision of 8 and 15 is the limit (unless the expo range needed more bytes for some novel `double`).  `DBL_TRUE_MIN` make `15 <-4.9406565e-324>`.

Comment: @anastaciu It does not bring _clarity_, it is a requirement.  `...` arguments are not made narrower when an `int` is expected and a `size_t` is passed.  `sprintf()` was pulling bytes off the ... parameters incorrectly because your code passed the wrong type of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what it's trying to tell you is that it's possible to end up with more digits than there is space to store them.  What happens if val is a really big number?